# Discord.js dming problem when using dm command on my disocrd server

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made a mass dm bot for my private discord server that I have been working on and doing giveaways with. Therefore I programmed a bot that will dm everyone for ex: if a giveaway is up or for game tournaments, etc. Every time I run the command +damall everything starts to work out perfectly fine but when a user who does not have me friended gets a dm from the bot it completely stops and I get an error.

For now here is the code:

```
const { Command } = require('discord-akairo');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const delay = (msec) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, msec));

class RecentCommand extends Command {
    constructor() {
        super('massdm',{
            aliases: ['dmall'],
            args: [
                {
                    id: 'ID'
                }
            ],
            channel: 'guild'
        });
    }

    async exec(message, client) {
        let Owner = message.author;
        if(Owner.id !== "727447049892659200") return message.reply("Only the bot owner can use this command!")
          let text = message.content.slice('+dmall'.length); // cuts off the /private part
          setTimeout(function(){
              try {
                  message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
                      delay(100);
                      member.send(text)
                  })

              }catch(e) {
                  
              }
        }, 1);

        return message.channel.send(`dming ${message.guild.members.cache.size} members`)

    }
}

module.exports = RecentCommand;
```

And this is the error I get when the bot dms an unfriended person:

[Debug Error for the bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQrc0.png)

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is a deliberate design decision on Discord's part - it prevents things like mass advertising and spam within the network. Use proper exception handling / `try`/`catch` blocks to handle and recover from these errors appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Some users have server dms off, so you cant dm them. HOWEVER, you can catch and ignore these errors to prevent your Process from crashing:

```js
const { Command } = require('discord-akairo');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const delay = (msec) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, msec));

class RecentCommand extends Command {
    constructor() {
        super('massdm',{
            aliases: ['dmall'],
            args: [
                {
                    id: 'ID'
                }
            ],
            channel: 'guild'
        });
    }

    async exec(message, client) {
        let Owner = message.author;
        if(Owner.id !== "727447049892659200") return message.reply("Only the bot owner can use this command!")
          let text = message.content.slice('+dmall'.length).split(/ +/); // cuts off the /private part
          setTimeout(async function(){
              try {
                  message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
                      await delay(1_000);
                      member.send(text.join(" ")).catch(x => { console.log("Couldn't DM " + member.user.tag) })//catch the error and do NOTHING with it.
                  })

              }catch(e) {
                  
              }
        }, 1);

        return message.channel.send(`dming ${message.guild.members.cache.size} members`)

    }
}

module.exports = RecentCommand;
```